# Find out what height would have my image if i will resize the width to another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize

I have a twitter bootstrap carousel in which I have images and iframes. Images work perfectly because they have img-responsive class and they resize. The iframes don't work like that. I have to give them a width and a height and change their width and height whenever the user resizes the browser.

The carousel can contains only images, only iframes, or images and iframes in the same time.

**How can I make the iframes work like the images? Have the same dimensions, resizes in the same way?**

My images are `750 x 427px`. The thing that passes my mind is to give the iframes width 100% of the container because this work and after this I have to find the height considering that if the width is for example 300px the height should direct proportional with the image dimensions which are `750 x 427px`.

**We can simply use the rule of three ? Or there is somehthing more complex using image ratio?**

Comment: If you are resizing the width of image and not height then its height will remain unchanged.

Comment: you can find out the height of image with this code, $('.image-class').height();

Answer (score 0):

Through .height() and .width methods.
You could use `$("#imgID").height()` to get its height and `$("#imgID").width()` to get its width. Of course the imgID is replaced with the actual ID of your image.

Comment: I still think, that using `$("#imgID").height()` every time, when the the screen is resized :
`$(window).resize(function(){
    .......
});`
and setting the height to iframe should work...